# Saving Bool/ tableView Checkmark - 3rd time lucky

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, data-persistence

This is third time I've posted this issues and am yet to get a working response.

So I have a fitness app, the user selected one workout before it been displayed as table view, when a cell is selected I want it to show that cell(containing an exercise) as completed by marking it with a checkmark. this works fine but I am struggling with how to save that check mark when the app is terminated and re launched.

Below I have given an example of one of the workout models and the table view controller.

Please can someone try and solve this!!

Thank you.

Josh

Workout model example -

```
import Foundation
class The600Workout {
    var workoutArray = [
        Workout(exercise: "Don't forget to warm up before every workout!", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Start with little/ no weight and work your way up", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "------------------------------------------------------------------", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Pull ups | 25 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Lunges | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Calf Raises | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Shoulder press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Push ups | 50 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Shrugs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Leg raises | 50 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "More Pull ups | 25 Reps", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Squats | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Incline Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Bicep curls | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
        Workout(exercise: "Tricep pull downs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", completed: false),
    ]
}
```

Table View Controller

```
import UIKit
class workoutTableView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var workoutTableView: UITableView!
    var navTitle: String = ""
    var workout = [Workout]()
    let tlabel = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setWorkout()
        workoutTableView.delegate = self
        workoutTableView.dataSource = self
        tlabel.text = navTitle
        tlabel.textAlignment = .center
        tlabel.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 30)
        tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navigationItem.titleView = tlabel
    }
    func setWorkout() {
        if navTitle == "The 600 Workout" {
            workout = The600Workout().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "5 Days for Muscle" {
            workout = FiveDaysForMuscle().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Marathon Ready" {
            workout = MarathonReady().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "HIIT @ Home" {
            workout = HIITAtHome().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Get Strong" {
            workout = GetStrong().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Body Weight Blast" {
            workout = BodyWeightBlast().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Bands Pump" {
          workout = BandsPump().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Quickie Warm up" {
            workout = QuickieWarmUp().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "The Best Circuit Workout" {
            workout = TheBestCircuit().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "The Gym HIIT Workout" {

            workout = GymHIIT().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "The Ultimate Workout" {
            workout = UltimateWorkout().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Warm up For Weights" {
            workout = WarmUpForWeights().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "6 Day Bro Split" {
          workout = SixDayBroSplit().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Explosive Workout" {
            workout = ExplosiveWorkout().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Strength Circuit" {
            workout = StrengthCircuit().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Killer Circuit" {    
            workout = KillerCircuit().workoutArray
        }
        else if navTitle == "Fitness Test" {
            workout = FitnessTest().workoutArray
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return workout.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        workout[indexPath.row].completed = !workout[indexPath.row].completed
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = workout[indexPath.row].completed ?  .checkmark : .none
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = workout[indexPath.row].exercise
        cell.accessoryType = workout[indexPath.row].completed ?  .checkmark : .none
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        cell.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3285208941, blue: 0.5748849511, alpha: 1)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        return cell   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save cell's current state(isSelected or not) to UserDefault. After relaunch, select the cell automatically according to UserDefaults data. For ex:

```
var selectedCell = 0 // For declaration

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        workout[indexPath.row].completed = !workout[indexPath.row].completed
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = workout[indexPath.row].completed ?  .checkmark : .none
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

        self.selectedCell = indexPath.row 
        UserDefaults.standart.set(self.selectedCell, forKey: "selectedCellIndex")
    }
```

And at cellForRowAt:

```
if indexPath.row == UserDefaults.standart.object(forKey: selectedCellIndex){
//select this cell and whatever you want
} else {
//Other cells 
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

To be able to save the `completed` state of each exercise separately you have to refactor the data model.

- Create a JSON file for the entire model – named for example `WorkoutData.json` – and put it into the application bundle. The file contains all workouts and their exercises and will be copied to the `Documents` folder on first launch or if you plan a *reset* function. The structure of the JSON file is

  ```
  [{"name":"The600Workout","exercises":
      [{"title":"Don't forget to warm up before every workout!", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Start with little/ no weight and work your way up", "completed": false},
      {"title":"------------------------------------------------------------------", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Pull ups | 25 Reps", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Lunges | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Calf Raises | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Shoulder press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Push ups | 50 Reps", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Shrugs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Leg raises | 50 Reps", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"More Pull ups | 25 Reps", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Squats | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Incline Bench press | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Bicep curls | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false},
      {"title":"Tricep pull downs | 50 Reps (Low weight)", "completed": false}]
  },
  {"name":"5 Days for Muscle","exercises": [ ... ]},
  {"name": ... [ ... ]},
  ...         
  ]
  ```
- Create two structs conforming to `Codable` which match the JSON data

  ```
  struct Exercise : Codable {
      let title : String
      var completed : Bool
  }

  struct Workout : Codable {
      let name : String
      let exercises : [Exercise]
  }
  ```
- In `viewDidLoad` get the URL to the file in the `Documents` folder with a computed property

  ```
  var workoutDataURL : URL {
          return try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("WorkoutData.json")
  }
  ```

  and check if the file exists. If not copy the file from the bundle to `Documents`.
- Create two methods to load and save the data with `JSONDecoder/JSONEncoder`
- Call the `load` method in `viewDidLoad` and reload the table view
- Call the `save` method whenever the user selects a cell to change the `completed` state.
- Rather than the endless `if - else if` expression you can simply get the workout with `workout = workoutArray.first{$0.name == navTitle}!`
- Delete all workout classes. They are not needed anymore.

This is a quite simple solution. A more efficient solution is to use a database like Core data. The benefit is you don't need to keep the entire data model in memory.

Comment: How would I create a JSON file and store the models in it? Thanks

Comment: There are two ways: 1) Use a text editor and build the JSON (which is plain text) with Find&Replace (as I quickly did in my example). 2) Create an array of your classes in code and encode the array with `JSONEncoder`. Both ways are simple and straightforward.